# Passing fstream to a function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to pass an fstream to a function which then writes struct to the file. I'm aware that you have to pass the stream by reference, but nothing is being written to the file at runtime. Heres what I have so far:

```
struct Record
{
    char name     [16];
    char phoneNum [16];
    float balance;
};

void newRec (fstream &);

int main()
{
    fstream ref;
    ref.open("prog2.dat", ios::in | ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);
    if(!ref.fail() )
    {
        int choice = menu(ref);
        system("CLS");

        while(choice != 6)
        {
            choice = menu(ref);
            system("CLS");
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "Error opening file. " << endl;

    return 0;
}


void newRec (fstream& ref)
{   
    Record rec;

    cout << "Enter customer name: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(rec.name, sizeof(rec.name));
    cout << "Enter customer phone number: ";
    cin >> rec.phoneNum;
    cout << "Enter beginning account balance: ";
    cin >> rec.balance;

    ref.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&rec), sizeof(rec));
}
```

rec being just a 3 member struct. Any ideas why this wouldn't work? I appreciate any help.
Note: I do have to use .write() as opposed to << as per my assignment

Comment: how is `ref` opened? Do the input operations succeed?

Comment: How is `Record` defined? Are any of the members pointers?

Comment: ref is opened in main and succeeds.

Comment: Record consists of 2 char strings (words), and a float

Comment: @user2044676, can you post that code?

Comment: iostreams are designed such that when an operation fails, it doesn't raise an exception by default. Check to see your program is not failing silently.

Comment: Posted the Record code.

Comment: @PedroLamarão, file opens properly in main, do I need to check its open in all the functions it is passed to?

Comment: @user2044676, if the file was opened successfully, you may assume it remains open until your program closes it. This in contrast with a pipe, which can be closed at any time by the other end.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio: maybe you are looking in the wrong directory, the file will be created in `Projects\Project_Name\Project_Name` when debugging, not in `Projects\Project_Name\Debug`.

Answer (score 0):

Streams work just like `cout` and `cin`. You would probably be better off using

```
ref << rec.name << "," << rec.phoneNum << "," << rec.balance << endl;
```

Comment: The assignment is mainly to focus on the advantages of using binary files. So I have to use the .write() method. I appreciate that though

Comment: In its current form you're focusing on the downsides, as your binary format is not portable.

Comment: Portability between different processor architectures doesn't seem to be a requirement.